# Can monit filesystem check handle NTFS disk?

Tags: monit

I am getting "unable to read filesystem '/dev/sdb1' state" from monit and don't understand why. fdisk -l shows /dev/sbd1: `/dev/sdb1        2048 283113471 283111424  135G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`
It is not mounted but exists under /dev/sdb1
The monit config looks like this

```
  group filesystem
  if space usage > 80 % then alert
  if inode usage > 80 % then alert
```

Can anybody give me a hint why monit alerts?

Best regards

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry your configuration is incomplete, it is lacking the check and mount point. For example:

> check filesystem NTFS_Disk with path /mnt/ntfs_disk

Make sure you are monitoring a mount point and not a device (like /dev/sdb1)

Comment: Hi T'Saavik,
thank you for your answer, which points me to the right direction! 

best regards
Thomas